# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString not working in iOS 7

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, uiwebview, ios7

I fallowed [this link](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-sample-project/) for adding image and text into UIWebview its working fine in iOS 6.x but its not working in iOS 7 i don't know why its happen. Then i find out the problem

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('insertImage', false, '%@')", imagePath]];
```

This function is not working, Actually its not updating image tag in to the main HTML. [Here is the example project](http://cl.ly/DWxy) and also [this is the main HTML file](http://pastie.org/8420385). Kindly guide me where its going wrong.

Comment: have a look at javaScriptCore framework in ios7. may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

This "insertImage" command allows to insert image to the current position of cursor in the text area.
But if I select "Post+" button on toolbar then it shows up some album and as soon as select one photo in the album then the text area lose the cursor.

This is the cause of this problem. So actually this insertImage command works but can't add image because there is no position of current cursor.

I tested this with the sample project that you attached as a link.